# Spark sql 2.1.1 thrift server - unable to move source hdfs to target

Tags: apache-spark-sql

It is related to this question [create table xxx as select * from yyy sometimes get error

][1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44223024/spark-sql-2-1-0-create-table-xxx-as-select-from-yyy-sometimes-get-error)

When using spark thrift server, execute multiple statement like `create table xxx as select * from yyy`, only first time will success, later tries will always fail, due to `java.io.IOException: Filesystem closed`, or `doAs` problems.

The full error stack trace:

```
17/05/29 08:44:53 ERROR thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation: Error executing query, currentState RUNNING,
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to move source hdfs://jzf-01:9000/user/hive/warehouse/task.db/task_107/.hive-staging_hive_2017-05-29_08-44-50_607_2388239917764085229-3/-ext-10000/part-00000 to destination hdfs://jzf-01:9000/user/hive/warehouse/task.db/task_107/part-00000;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.loadTable(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:766)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:374)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable.sideEffectResult(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:221)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable.doExecute(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.CreateHiveTableAsSelectCommand.run(CreateHiveTableAsSelectCommand.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:592)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:699)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation.org$apache$spark$sql$hive$thriftserver$SparkExecuteStatementOperation$$execute(SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:231)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation$$anon$1$$anon$2.run(SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation$$anon$1$$anon$2.run(SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:171)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1656)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation$$anon$1.run(SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:184)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to move source hdfs://jzf-01:9000/user/hive/warehouse/task.db/task_107/.hive-staging_hive_2017-05-29_08-44-50_607_2388239917764085229-3/-ext-10000/part-00000 to destination hdfs://jzf-01:9000/user/hive/warehouse/task.db/task_107/part-00000
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.moveFile(Hive.java:2644)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.replaceFiles(Hive.java:2892)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.loadTable(Hive.java:1640)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.Shim_v0_14.loadTable(HiveShim.scala:728)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$loadTable$1.apply$mcV$sp(HiveClientImpl.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$loadTable$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$loadTable$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$withHiveState$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:279)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.liftedTree1$1(HiveClientImpl.scala:226)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.retryLocked(HiveClientImpl.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.withHiveState(HiveClientImpl.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.loadTable(HiveClientImpl.scala:675)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$loadTable$1.apply$mcV$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:768)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$loadTable$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:766)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$loadTable$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:766)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:97)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Filesystem closed
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.checkOpen(DFSClient.java:798)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getEZForPath(DFSClient.java:2966)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getEZForPath(DistributedFileSystem.java:1906)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.client.HdfsAdmin.getEncryptionZoneForPath(HdfsAdmin.java:262)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.Hadoop23Shims$HdfsEncryptionShim.isPathEncrypted(Hadoop23Shims.java:1221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.moveFile(Hive.java:2607)
    ... 59 more
17/05/29 08:44:53 ERROR thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation: Error running hive query:
org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to move source hdfs://jzf-01:9000/user/hive/warehouse/task.db/task_107/.hive-staging_hive_2017-05-29_08-44-50_607_2388239917764085229-3/-ext-10000/part-00000 to destination hdfs://jzf-01:9000/user/hive/warehouse/task.db/task_107/part-00000;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation.org$apache$spark$sql$hive$thriftserver$SparkExecuteStatementOperation$$execute(SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:266)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation$$anon$1$$anon$2.run(SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation$$anon$1$$anon$2.run(SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:171)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1656)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation$$anon$1.run(SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:184)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This is a normal `create table select as` log

```
17/05/29 08:42:30 INFO cluster.YarnScheduler: Removed TaskSet 1.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
17/05/29 08:42:30 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: ResultStage 1 (run at AccessController.java:0) finished in 2.079 s
17/05/29 08:42:30 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Job 1 finished: run at AccessController.java:0, took 2.100557 s
17/05/29 08:42:30 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 2: get_table : db=task tbl=task_106
17/05/29 08:42:30 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=root    ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_table : db=task tbl=task_106    
17/05/29 08:42:30 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 2: get_table : db=task tbl=task_106
17/05/29 08:42:30 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=root    ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_table : db=task tbl=task_106    
17/05/29 08:42:30 INFO metadata.Hive: Replacing src:hdfs://jzf-01:9000/user/hive/warehouse/task.db/task_106/.hive-staging_hive_2017-05-29_08-42-26_232_2514893773205547001-1/-ext-10000/part-00000, dest: hdfs://jzf-01:9000/user/hive/warehouse/task.db/task_106/part-00000, Status:true
17/05/29 08:42:30 INFO metadata.Hive: Replacing src:hdfs://jzf-01:9000/user/hive/warehouse/task.db/task_106/.hive-staging_hive_2017-05-29_08-42-26_232_2514893773205547001-1/-ext-10000/part-00001, dest: hdfs://jzf-01:9000/user/hive/warehouse/task.db/task_106/part-00001, Status:true
```

This is the fail one, after some `get_table`, it is executing some `drop_table`, and then cause the `Filesystem.close`, finally `unable to move source`

```
17/05/29 08:42:50 INFO cluster.YarnScheduler: Removed TaskSet 6.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
17/05/29 08:42:50 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: ResultStage 6 (run at AccessController.java:0) finished in 2.567 s
17/05/29 08:42:50 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Job 3 finished: run at AccessController.java:0, took 2.819549 s
17/05/29 08:42:51 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 6: get_table : db=task tbl=task_107
17/05/29 08:42:51 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=root    ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_table : db=task tbl=task_107    
17/05/29 08:42:51 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 6: get_table : db=task tbl=task_107
17/05/29 08:42:51 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=root    ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_table : db=task tbl=task_107    
17/05/29 08:42:51 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 6: get_database: task
17/05/29 08:42:51 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=root    ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_database: task  
17/05/29 08:42:51 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 6: get_table : db=task tbl=task_107
17/05/29 08:42:51 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=root    ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_table : db=task tbl=task_107    
17/05/29 08:42:51 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 6: get_database: task
17/05/29 08:42:51 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=root    ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_database: task  
17/05/29 08:42:51 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 6: get_table : db=task tbl=task_107
17/05/29 08:42:51 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=root    ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_table : db=task tbl=task_107    
17/05/29 08:42:51 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 6: drop_table : db=task tbl=task_107
17/05/29 08:42:51 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=root    ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=drop_table : db=task tbl=task_107   
17/05/29 08:42:51 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MFieldSchema" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
17/05/29 08:42:51 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MOrder" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
17/05/29 08:42:51 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MFieldSchema" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
17/05/29 08:42:51 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MOrder" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
17/05/29 08:42:51 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MFieldSchema" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
17/05/29 08:42:51 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MOrder" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
17/05/29 08:42:52 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MFieldSchema" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
17/05/29 08:42:52 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MOrder" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
17/05/29 08:42:52 INFO metastore.hivemetastoressimpl: deleting  hdfs://jzf-01:9000/user/hive/warehouse/task.db/task_107
17/05/29 08:42:52 INFO fs.TrashPolicyDefault: Namenode trash configuration: Deletion interval = 0 minutes, Emptier interval = 0 minutes.
17/05/29 08:42:52 INFO metastore.hivemetastoressimpl: Deleted the diretory hdfs://jzf-01:9000/user/hive/warehouse/task.db/task_107
17/05/29 08:42:52 ERROR thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation: Error executing query, currentState RUNNING,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `hive.exec.staging-dir` in your `hive-site.xml` like this:

```
<property>
  <name>hive.exec.stagingdir</name>
  <value>/tmp/hive/spark-${user.name}</value>
</property>
```

This worked for a customer who upgraded from 1.6.2 to 2.1.1 and who had that same problem with CTAS. On our dev cluster, doing this got us past your particular error, but we still have some HDFS permission issues we are working through.

Hope this helps.

Comment: cool! this solves it graceful. Thanks finally someone know what I'm talking about.

Comment: Hey, one thing I forgot to add. The CTAS table will be `TEXTFILE` unless you set `hive.default.fileformat` to parquet or orc, so searching it might be slower than you expect.

Comment: I'm using `create table xx stored as orc as select * from yyy`, I guess this will be stored as orc?

Comment: Oh, of course. My CTAS is generated by a BI tool without the `stored as`, so I wasn't thinking. This setting could save you some typing or make the SQL more portable.

Answer (score 1):

add the property to hdfs-site.xml

```
  <property>
      <name>fs.hdfs.impl.disable.cache</name>
      <value>true</value>
  </property>
```

Reason: spark and hdfs use the same api (at the bottom they use the same instance).

When beeline close a filesystem instance . It close the thriftserver's filesystem instance too.
Second beeline try to get instance , it will always report "Caused by: java.io.IOException: Filesystem closed"

Please check this issue here:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21725

Comment: @user8142092 -- Thanks very much for your help!  You have saved my day.  I have another SO post for the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48592337/hive-hadoop-intermittent-failure-unable-to-move-source-to-destination/48611442#48611442  It is now solved thanks to your answer.

Comment: @user8142092- This method works.  But then the queries become very slow.  Queries that used to finish with a few seconds now take ~40 s to execute.  Do you see the same on your site?

Comment: @leeyuiwah Sorry to reply to you so late, we did not clearly feel the existence of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This 100% is a bug, I don't know how to describe it, but I could tell how I bypass it.

After hundreds of fails, I found this happens when execute `create table as select`

- using jdbc, if execute it once in one connection, then try it in another connection, it will 100% fails. This nearly kill me, cause it takes too long to realize that `spring simpleDatasource -> jdbcTemplate` just use different connection for each statement. There's a pool, so I set pool size to 1, it works normal.
- using beeline, if execute it once, and stop beeline, and start beeline again, it will 100% fail

The only way I found to bypass this bug, is EACH TIME I WANT TO EXECUTE,

- start a ssh session
- in this session, start beeline, and connect to drift server
- execute the `create table as select` statement
- destroy the ssh session

This is the only way to execute `create table as select` multiple times in a single spark sql thrift jdbc server lifetime.