# Hive/Hadoop intermittent failure: Unable to move source to destination

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql

There have been some SO articles about `Hive/Hadoop` "Unable to move source" error.  Many of them point to permission problem.

However, in my site I saw the same error but I am quite sure that it is not related to permission problem.  This is because the problem is intermittent -- it worked one day but failed on another day.

I thus looked more deeply into the error message.  It was complaining about failing to move from a

```
.../.hive-stating_hive.../-ext-10000/part-00000-${long-hash}
```

source path to a destination path of

```
.../part-00000-${long-hash}
```

folder.  Would this observation ring a bell with someone?

This error was triggered by a super simple test query: just insert a row into a test table (see below)

**Error message**

```
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: 
Unable to move source 
hdfs://namenodeHA/apps/hive/warehouse/some_db.db/testTable1/.hive-staging_hive_2018-02-02_23-02-13_065_2316479064583526151-5/-ext-10000/part-00000-832944cf-7db4-403b-b02e-55b6e61b1af1-c000 
to destination 
hdfs://namenodeHA/apps/hive/warehouse/some_db.db/testTable1/part-00000-832944cf-7db4-403b-b02e-55b6e61b1af1-c000;
```

**Query that triggered this error (but only intermittently)**

```
insert into testTable1
values (2);
```

Comment: I also faced this issue sometime back but it was related to parquet file metadata. Is the file type is parquet.

Comment: @Manu — yes the file type is parquet.

Comment: one more question, you are using hive on spark or map reduce?

Comment: I am using hive on spark. Thanks!

Comment: Please use this property and let me know if this work. I will ans in answer section : set spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet=false

Comment: I was reading hive on spark documentation and this note may help us: Note that you must have a version of Spark which does not include the Hive jars. Meaning one which was not built with the Hive profile. If you will use Parquet tables, it's recommended to also enable the "parquet-provided" profile. Otherwise there could be conflicts in Parquet dependency. To remove Hive jars from the installation, simply use the following command under your Spark repository:

Comment: @Manu -- Thanks a lot!  I will look into that.  Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the help.  I have found a solution.  I am providing my own answer here.

The problem was with a "CTAS" `create table as ...` operation that preceded the failing `insert` command due to an inappropriate close of the file system.  The telltale sign was that there would be an `IOException: Filesystem closed` message shown together with the failing `HiveException: Unable to move source ... to destination` operation.  ( I found the log message from my Spark Thrift Server not my application log )

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Filesystem closed
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.checkOpen(DFSClient.java:808)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getEZForPath(DFSClient.java:3288)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getEZForPath(DistributedFileSystem.java:2093)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.client.HdfsAdmin.getEncryptionZoneForPath(HdfsAdmin.java:289)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.Hadoop23Shims$HdfsEncryptionShim.isPathEncrypted(Hadoop23Shims.java:1221)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.moveFile(Hive.java:2607)
```

The solution was actually from another SO article: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47067350/1168041

But here I provide an excerpt in case that article is gone:

> add the property to hdfs-site.xml
>
> ```
> <property>
>     <name>fs.hdfs.impl.disable.cache</name>
>     <value>true</value>
> </property>
> ```
>
> Reason: spark and hdfs use the same api (at the bottom they use the same instance).
>
> When beeline close a filesystem instance . It close the thriftserver's
>   filesystem instance too. Second beeline try to get instance , it will
>   always report "Caused by: java.io.IOException: Filesystem closed"
>
> Please check this issue here:
>
> https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21725

I was not using `beeline` but the problem with CTAS was the same.

My test sequence:

```
insert into testTable1
values (11)

create table anotherTable as select 1

insert into testTable1
values (12)
```

Before the fix, any insert would failed after the `create table as …` 
 After the fix, this problem was gone.